# Zabbix web scenario zul login form

Tags: authentication, zabbix, scenarios

I must create a web scenario for check my website.
I created a new scenario and for step 1 i check login page: all ok.

Now I would to login and then test some internal link.

I added a second step for login, and added 2 "post fileds"

j_username -> {username}

j_password -> {passowrd}

**j_username** and **j_password** are the names of the fileds in the login form created by zul framework.

I also added a check for welcome string of logged user.
I receive a 200 status but not the "welcome string" then i suppose that not logged in (and 200 code is referred to login page that tell me to login).

If I add a third step with a new internal url I receive `Error: response code "302" did not match any of the required status codes "200"` that confirm that I m not logged in.

I looked for examples of "tutorial with login" on the net but I didn't find any that worked.

On the other hand, I have no problems with checking wsdl or rest (always with username / passowrd)

Answer (score 0):

The 302 response means that you are being redirected, but I can't say if it happens after a successful logon or an unsuccessful one.

Here you can find some [real life scenario](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_monitoring/example) examples.

Please note that Zabbix can't post into forms (ie: fill in a form then click submit), you need to specify URL and parameters and/or variables and values to post.